# 19v Laptop (11.1v battery) on 3x6v sealed lead-acid batteries?

Tags: batteries

I have a laptop with 11.1v battery and 19v charger voltage, is it safe to use 3 sealed lead-acid 6v batteries in series?
And if I will to use 6 batteries to achieve 18v, is it better to connect each 2 in parallel, then in series the 3 packs of 2? Or each 3 in series, then in parallel both packs of 3

Comment: As a supply to the laptop's power input, or a replacement for the internal battery? The former should work fine. If you're paralleling batteries they need to be charged to the same voltage before connecting them together.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with those experiments!
A Lead-Acid battery of 6V has up to ~7V when fully charged.

If you want to connect batteries in series or in parallel, you need to have the same type for all of them. Otherwise, they won't discharge and charge the same way and can get damaged.

Comment: extra careful with Li-based batteries. They like to catch fire and explode when not charged properly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery